How to access internal integer representation of timestamps in postgresql?
I want to access the integer representation of timestamps in postgresql from javascript, it seems postgresql drivers for javascript do not support the result-column format codes in the bind message. Writing a new driver / modifying an existing one almost seems necessary. Are there any drivers which support binary result format instead of text? Or some other approach?
Tried to find a function in postgres which would allow access to the integer representation of the timestamp, and casting, but no luck.
SELECT current_timestamp::int8;

What do you get on the JavaScript side?

Seems like this works:
CREATE CAST (timestamp AS int8) WITHOUT FUNCTION;
CREATE CAST (timestamptz AS int8) WITHOUT FUNCTION;
SELECT current_timestamp::timestamptz::int8, current_timestamp::timestamp::int8;




current_timestamp
current_timestamp




780063396480715
780063396480715



